# Taxonomy term as node css class

Tags: 6, nodes, taxonomy-terms, theming

Kind of similar to my previous question, but apparently doesn't work the same way: is there an easy way to use a taxonomy term or a token as node css class to theme different pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit you node-type.tpl.php for this.

```
<?php
    foreach($node->taxonomy as $term){
            $term_classes[] = $term->name;
    }
?>
```

And print those classes in your node content wrapper.

```
<div class="content <?php print implode(' ', $term_classes); ?>">
    <?php print $content ?>
</div>
```